# How to share Symfony2 FOSRestBundle routes with client?

Tags: javascript, rest, symfony, fosrestbundle

I'm working on a RESTful API with FOSRestBundle, and I was thinking along the lines of creating a dictionary of API urls for clients.

It just feels like a waste of time and unnecessary complexity to involve just-in-time twig/path helper calls once the API is established. And I'm seeing a lot of it in our javascript client instead of either using a convention or dumping all the routes once as some kind of static dictionary.

After all, upcoming mobile clients won't even have the php/html/js context where twig/path is available.

What is the best practice to communicate the available API calls across clients?

Comment: `php app/console router:debug | grep /api`^^

Comment: +1 for a quick dump solution.

Comment: @moonwave99: How about a best practice? Especially for web client. I feel like not wearing pants when I just write /user/items next to {{path('long route key that noone really cares about')}}

Comment: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle ?